# jQuery Checkbox select

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am stuck with this problem.

I have one textbox

```
<input id="chkIsHyperLink" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
```

And one `<div>`

```
<div ID="IsHyperLink" Visible="false" >
     <tr>
         <td>
              <b>URL:</b>
         </td>
         <td>
             <input type="text" id="txtUrl" name="URL" value="" runat="server" 
                    class="text-input small-input" maxlength="100" />
         </td>
         <td>
         </td>
     </tr>
</div>
```

And with the help of jquery, I want output such that if the user clicks on a `checkbox` then `textbox` should shown otherwise it should be hidden.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to show/hide the input with a click ?

**Edit:**

Is this what u want ?
Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/hfpVc/11/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a checkbox like this somewhere:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show_textbox" />

$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#show_textbox').bind('click', function() {
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         $("#txtUrl").show();
      } else {
         $("#txtUrl").hide();
      }
   });
});
```

HTH :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do this by either checking the status of the checkbox with an eventhandler or by letting the checkbox fire a js method onchange.

add the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" onchange="checkBox();" />
```

And the script

```
<script>
function checkBox() {
   if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
      $("#txtUrl").show();
   } else {
      $("#txtUrl").hide();
   }
}
</script>
```

There are more neat way of doing this but this should do the trick :)

If you are interested in eventhandlers have a look at the bind api in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#<%=myCheckBox.ClientID%>').bind('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#<%=txtUrl.ClientID%>").show();
    } else {
      $("#<%=txtUrl.ClientID%>").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Note that I'm referencing the `ClientID` property of the server-side controls, since your HTML elements are set to `runat="server"` in your ASP.NET code.  There are other ways to accomplish this, but this way has always worked well for me.